# Смена фона div при наведени на ссылку

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Пожалуйста подскажите есть структура

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="" id="link1">11111</a>
    <a href="" id="link2">22222</a>
    <a href="" id="link3">333333</a>
</div>
```

как сделать чтобы при наведении на `#link1 #link2 #link3` менялся фон `#menu`

ЗАРАНЕЕ ВАС ВСЕХ БЛАГОДАРЮ!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$("#menu a").hover(function(){
    $("#menu").css("background", "#f00");
},
function(){
    $("#menu").css("background", "#00f");
});
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не получается (

может я не правильно пишу код?

задаю в в таком виде и перед меню

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#menu a").hover(function(){
    $("#menu").css("background", "#f00");
},
function(){
    $("#menu").css("background", "#00f");
});
}
</script>


и еще вопрос если css указан картинкой как правильно прописать команду
background: url(images/menu.png) no-repeat bottom;


Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Для начала надо подключить jQuery (Например: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js);

Если позиционирование фоновой картинки не меняется, то достаточно background-image: url(....);

Comment: библиотека подключена, не получается.

Comment: Нужно ещё в `$(document).ready` или вставлять скрипт после разметки.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z653m/

Пардон, hover работает только до версии 1.9

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!
последний вопрос если это будет картинка как правильно задать комманду?

Comment: $('#img_id').attr('src','picture.png');

Comment: @Pepperok, $("#menu").css("background-image", "url(path/to/image.jpg)");

Comment: почему-бы просто [класс не переключать](http://jsfiddle.net/6xyXh/) ?

    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#menu').on('mouseover mouseout', 'a', function () {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('hovered');
        });
    });